# matplotlib RuntimeError: In select_charmap: Could not set the charmap using latex

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I try to run the following python code (Python 3.4.7 + scipy installed; MikTeX 2.9.4476 installed; Windows 7)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import rc

rc('text', usetex=True)

# plotting
data = range(100)
plt.plot(data, data, label='0.3 m')

plt.legend()
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.savefig("test.svg")
# plt.show()
```

and get the following errors if I use plt.savefig("test.svg") or any other vector graphics format. Without this saving command everything works fine. Printed Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\ICCAP\S_SVN\ETHAN\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    plt.savefig("test.svg")
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 688, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1539, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2230, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_svg.py", line 1206, in print_svg
    return self._print_svg(filename, svgwriter, fh_to_close, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_svg.py", line 1234, in _print_svg
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1133, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2304, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py", line 482, in draw
    self._legend_box.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py", line 286, in draw
    c.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py", line 286, in draw
    c.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py", line 286, in draw
    c.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py", line 286, in draw
    c.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py", line 867, in draw
    self._text.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 792, in draw
    mtext=mtext)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_svg.py", line 1152, in draw_tex
    self._draw_text_as_path(gc, x, y, s, prop, angle, ismath="TeX")
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_svg.py", line 957, in _draw_text_as_path
    return_new_glyphs_only=True)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Qt5\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", line 346, in get_glyphs_tex
    font.select_charmap(charmap_code)
RuntimeError: In select_charmap: Could not set the charmap
```

any ideas what's going wrong/ could be improved?

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue, and I fixed it by upgrading `matplotlib` to `1.5.1`. It seems to be related with Matplotlib trying to render some fonts and not catching an exception that should've been caught.

Related: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5770#issuecomment-168212746